# Server.Mappath in C# classlibrary

Tags: c#, server.mappath

How can i use the server.mappath method in a C# class library class ,which acts as my BusinessLayer for My ASP.NET WEbsite

Answer (score 122, accepted):

By calling it?

```
var path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("default.aspx");
```

Make sure you add a reference to the System.Web assembly.

Comment: i should say that system.web assembly does not exist in .net framework 4

Comment: The worst solution! What if we need to use Business Layer classes out of HTTP Context?

Comment: Here is the right answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12294458/asp-net-mvc-4-use-server-mappath-in-business-layer

Comment: This answer is both not portable (outside of web applications) and not testable in unit tests.  I agree with Ninja here.  You can use IOC to inject the value, perhaps with an interface.

Answer (score 25):

You can get the base path by using the following code and append your needed path with that.

```
string  path = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

Answer (score 7):

You should reference System.Web and call:

```
  HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(...)
```

Answer (score 7):

Use this [System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.mappath.aspx).

```
HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/file")
```

Wonder why nobody mentioned it here.

Comment: What's the difference between this and System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath ?

I couldn't find any thing concrete between the two

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you could abstract this as a dependency and create an IVirtualPathResolver. This way your service classes wouldn't be bound to System.Web and you could create another implementation if you wanted to reuse your logic in a different UI technology.

Answer (score 2):

```
HostingEnvironment.MapPath
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(path);
```

Answer (score 2):

Architecturally, System.web should not be referred in Business Logic Layer (BLL). Employ BLL into the solution structure to follow the separate of concern principle so refer System.Web is a bad practice. BLL should not load/run in Asp.net context. Because of the reason you should consider using of `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` instead of `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath`